# HTML PHP Text Box (simple?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, textbox

**Intro:** I've been wandering the internet trying to find a solution to no avail. I'm a PHP noob and my html and css are marginal.

**Problem:**
I want to create a simple? text box on a website that can be edited and saved and displayed on the website.

If I could avoid PHP or other languages that would be fine but I think the save part is going to require some server site processing. Because I don't expect a large amount of data, storing the text boxes in a xml file or similar should be fine. (no need for a db)

I'm looking for the most simple and hopefully complete solution as I am a rookie with this stuff.

Notes:
I should be able to copy and paste the html code anywhere to create more text/comment boxes. (maybe i need to change a ID or something that's fine)

I hope the comment box has no real text/character limits and any characters or quotes or html or other language is displayed as was written.

It cam be ugly, the focus is functional and simple.

I found this was closest to what I wanted but I could not get it working at all. Maybe its a language my computer or server was not happy with. **[LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71352/Editable-Panel-Text-Box-on-a-Webpage-with-a-Capabi)**

Comment: So basically a bulletin board where people can post a small message? If that's what you need I can do that for you.

Comment: Actually its a place for myself and others to store notes. The webpage will be password protected via .htaccess, i know that's not the best security, but the data is not sensitive. Its really just a single webpage with multiple text boxes of editable and savable notes. No need for dates, authors, ratings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by acknowledging that you *will* need PHP, and unless you have a proper login system or alternatively a CAPTCHA, this project can be prone to a bot that floods a bunch of messages - I know from experience. All you need to make is an HTML form which will be used to type and submit the text to this public "bulletin board":

```
<form method='post' action='http://yoursite/newmessage.php' type='submit'>
    <input type='text' name='text' placeholder="Type message here"/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

This form will send whatever the user types in the text input to a PHP file, which will then save it. Now, for something very simple like this you can or cannot use a database.

**Benefits of a database:**

1. More secure
2. If two people try to add a message simultaneously, less issues there

**Benefits of a text file**

1. Much simpler to make

Since you are not storing any personal data, a text file will be fine. You can name this whatever you want on the server - it doesn't matter. This will be the PHP file:

```
<?php
    $newText = $_REQUEST['text']; //data submitted from HTML form
    $currentText = file_get_contents('data.txt'); //txt file in same folder as this PHP file_get_contents
    $concatText = $currentText . '<div><p>' . $newText . '</p></div>';
    file_put_contents('data.txt',$concatText);
?>
```

Lastly, displaying the data on the HTML page is easy. First make sure you are running this on a server that executes PHP, and it'd help to rename index.html to index.php:

```
<?php
    $all_data = file_get_contents('data.txt');
    echo $all_data;
?>
```

**Edit** I just saw that you want it password-protected. Simply create another text input in the form and in PHP verify that it matches a string.

Comment: I've tried what you have sent. It works. Which is the first time I have gotten anything PHP working on my site!

Anyway, the problems are:
1. the submit its not really a text box, i would sometimes like to add multiple lines and still be readable inside the text box.
2. How can I edit a previous comment? it seems it rather posts and appends to the text file, no way to edit the previous comment.
3.I will be hopefully have multiple text boxes on the page will hold text. and when editing I would like it to populate with the previously saved text so I can just make changes as required.

Comment: Change the input element to a textarea element for it to be larger. In order to edit a previous comment, things get more tricky, because then you have to structure the entire text file differently so you can go back to previous ones to edit. You would have to create an imploded array of comments - which means you have to separate each comment by some character like | in the text file so you know where one starts and ends.

Comment: I could have a separate text file for each comment box if that's easier but i dont know how to solve the other problem. Basically I want a text fox of similar functionality to the one I'm typing in now here on stackoverflow, it can be more crude and similar functionality would be great.